# SAS pseudo codes execution: if VAR(t+1)>VAR(t) then output VAR(t)

Tags: sas

I have a pseudo code using SAS that I don't know how to execute, the logic is this:

If within a same code, interest(t+1)is less than interest(t), then output coupon=interest(t), keep date, code. In the example below, it is observation 6.

```
obs.    date    code    interest
1   1/1/2015    1   0.2
2   1/2/2015    1   0.5
3   1/3/2015    1   1.9
4   1/4/2015    1   2.5
5   1/5/2015    1   3.8
6   1/1/2015    2   2.1
7   1/2/2015    2   0
8   1/3/2015    2   0.1
9   1/4/2015    2   0.2
10  1/5/2015    2   0.3
```

output sample should look like either:

```
obs.    date    code    interest  coupon
1       1/1/2015     2    2.1      2.1
```

or

```
obs.    date    code    interest  coupon
1   1/1/2015    1        0.2
2   1/2/2015    1        0.5
3   1/3/2015    1        1.9
4   1/4/2015    1        2.5
5   1/5/2015    1        3.8
6   1/1/2015    2        2.1       2.1
7   1/2/2015    2        0
8   1/3/2015    2        0.1
9   1/4/2015    2        0.2
10  1/5/2015    2        0.3
```

Example coding is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should also provide an example of how the output data will look.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Thanks. Added it.

Comment: How does the variable code come in to play? It seems to group observations somehow since the date resets at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare a record with the subsequent record, one way is to merge the table on to itself, with the second version starting from record number 2.  Therefore record 1 in table1 will join with record 2 in table2 etc.  You also need to rename the variables in table2 in order to do the comparison.

```
data have;
  infile datalines;
  input dt ddmmyy10. code interest;
  format dt date9.;
datalines;
1/1/2015    1   0.2
1/2/2015    1   0.5
1/3/2015    1   1.9
1/4/2015    1   2.5
1/5/2015    1   3.8
1/1/2015    2   2.1
1/2/2015    2   0
1/3/2015    2   0.1
1/4/2015    2   0.2
1/5/2015    2   0.3
;
run;

data want;
  merge have
        have (firstobs=2 keep=code interest rename=(code=code_1 interest=interest_1));
if code=code_1 and interest_1<interest then coupon=interest;
drop code_1 interest_1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are looking for is **"if INTEREST at obs n+1 is less than Previous record then COUPON=INTEREST"**, then the below code will do the trick for you,

```
data have;
  infile datalines;
  input dt ddmmyy10. code interest;
  format dt date9.;
datalines;
1/1/2015    1   0.2
1/2/2015    1   0.5
1/3/2015    1   1.9
1/4/2015    1   2.5
1/5/2015    1   3.8
1/1/2015    2   2.1
1/2/2015    2   0
1/3/2015    2   0.1
1/4/2015    2   0.2
1/5/2015    2   0.3
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  coupon=0.0;
  /* Using the LAG() function check the previous record */
  if interest < lag(interest) then coupon=interest; 
run;
```

Comment: I don't think this is right.  You're comparing 2.1 with 3.8, but they belong to different codes (3.8 is code 1, 2.1 is code 2).

I believe the OP is comparing 2.1 with the next value, 0.

Comment: Yes @Keith is correct. The key point is find the value within each code. But the lag function idea is very helpful. Thanks!